# How to load data from database using autocomplete?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
      $( "#user_role" ).autocomplete({ 
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/search_username",
                dataType: "json",
                data: request,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.response == 'true') {
                       response($data);
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            //Do something extra on select... Perhaps add user id to hidden input    
        },

    });
}());
```

here is my HTML,

```
<input type="text" id="user_role" name="user_role">
```

Here is my controller,

```
function search_username() {

    $keyword=$this->input->get('term');
    $this->load->model('chat_model');
    $data=$this->chat_model->GetRow($keyword);        
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Here is my model

```
public function GetRow($keyword) {       

    $this->db->like('user_type', $keyword, 'both');
    return $this->db->get('lc_user_types')->result_array();
}
```

What I my trying to do is to load data form database using ajax but it's response is `no properties` but data is already there in table, please anyone help me for get rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check this function it will return result or not

```
public function GetRow($keyword) {       
    $this->db->like('user_type', $keyword, 'both');
   return $this->db->get('lc_user_types')->result_array();


}
```

If it returning change the function

```
$(function() {
   $( "#user_role" ).autocomplete({ 
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/search_username",
            dataType: "json",
            data: request,
            success: function(data){
                response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                        return {
                            id:key,
                            label: value,
                            value: value
                        };
                    }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        //Do something extra on select... Perhaps add user id to hidden input    
    },

});
}());
```

Comment: Have you change javascript function. Manage the result array as key value. Ie  array([0]=>'sudhir',[1]=>'prasanga')

Comment: In response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                       console.log(value); // check what returns
                    }));

Comment: Thanks a lot sudhir.. it's getting

Comment: [{"user_type":"Admin","user_type_id":"1"},{"user_type":"Agent","user_type_id":"2"}]